# Wordpress functions.php conditional include another functions file

Tags: functions, embed, include

In my wordpress functions.php I have calls to include other function files.  For example like so:

```
include("functions/articles.php");
include("functions/custompost.php");
```

Within those files I have all my functions that pertain to specific pages on the site.

What I want to do is this:

```
//Articles custom functions
function articles_fn() {
 if ( is_page_template( 'page_templates/articles.php' ) ) {
    
        include("functions/articles.php");

    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'articles_fn');


//CustomPostType custom functions
function cpt_fn() {
 if ( is_page_template( 'page_templates/custompost.php' ) ) {
    
        include("functions/custompost.php");

    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_fn');
```

...but this doesn't work.  Any help is hugely appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What doesn't work? What's in those files?

Comment: What's in those files isn't relevant; they just contain regular functions that pertain to the articles and customposttype pages.  They work absolutely fine if I include them unconditionally (as in the top block of code), but if I try and only include them on specific page templates (2nd block of code), it doesn't work.